# Does all the plugins present in the avaliable tab compatible with the version of master jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Say if I have 2 Jenkins master

A: Jenkins version2.22
B: Jenkins version 2.35

So when I go to manage Jenkins --> manage plugins I see available plugins.
Does that mean that all the plugins listed in available plugins are compatible with that particular version of Jenkins?

For Eg: Available plugins in Jenkins master A are compatible with 2.22 versions of Jenkins.
and Available plugins in Jenkins master B are compatible with 2.35 version Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins shows the latest plugins' versions be default.

To show plugins matching your jenkins version you need to go Manage jenkins -> manage plugins -> advanced and change URL in "Update Site". For me it looks like `https://updates.jenkins.io/stable-2.235/update-center.json`

You can check https://updates.jenkins.io/ for json files available for your version.

Comment: Do you mean if Jenkins's version is 2.235 all the plugins visible in available plugins are the only ones that are compatible/supported with 2.235?

Comment: With configured URL in "Update Site" you will get plugins' versions compatible with your jenkins version in Updates and Available Dials.

Comment: The reason for asking this is I want to know how Jenkins fetches the plugins which are compatible with that specific version. I have an environment where I want to have my own update center for which I want to create version specific repository so if Jenkins version is 2.235 I want to have a repo which only contains the plugins compatible with 2.235 .